# Opencv 3.4.3 gstreamer build on Raspberry pi 3 last Raspbian stretch not working

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, opencv3.0

I've been working for a while on a computer vision project using opencv on a raspberry pi, Transmitting via UDP video and information to a Desktop Qt based application.

I've been the last few days stuck on a problem and I can not solve it by myself. The thing is, my opencv application on my raspberry pi 3 were working perfectly but I needed to use gstreamer for sending the output of the application via UDP to my desktop Qt based app.

Opencv accepts gstreamer pipelines as input and output via videocapture and videowriter, but for that opencv needs to be built with gstreamer support, and here is where I am facing the problem. While I build opencv 3.4.3 on the raspberry pi with gstreamer support I can no longer use the typical Videocapture cap(0) for opening the default camera, it gets hung just here. The application doesn't throw any error or anything, it just doesn't open up anything and keeps in that state. I know the problem is right there because I have several debug messages on the app, and it is stuck in this. Besides that, if I use a gstreamer pipeline as input instead of 0 (default camera) it works. The problem is just with default camera, maybe V4l messed up I don't know. Using gstreamer pipelines on the terminal, separately, works perfectly.

Researching a bit, I realized gst-plugins-bad, which I need, uses some opencv libraries, and I saw on a nvidia forum that this was causing some trouble on jestson boards exactly because of this, but I didn't see a clear solution. I don't know if gst-plugins-bad is overriding my opencv installation and that is the cause (gst-plugins-bad uses an older version of opencv). In any case, I have tried installing opencv 3.4.3 after gst-plugins-bad also with no luck. It is like V4l isn't working properly on my opencv 3.4.3 build.

On the other hand, I've tried to build opencv 3.4.3 on my desktop ubuntu 18.04 all along with gstreamer 1.14.1, and it works all right, and understands videcapture cap(0) all right, as expected, and I can run the application intended for the raspberry pi with no problems, even adding gstreamer pipelines to input and output, everything all right. The raspberry gstreamer is version 1.10 I think.

I am about to try to build and install from source gstreamer 1.14.1 which is working along opencv on my desktop Ubuntu, on my raspberry pi, but it's going to be long and painful. I just would really appreciate it if somebody can throw a bit of light about what is happening here.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When last I checked(a few years ago), the best way to solve this was to build a "gstreamer plugin"... this is assuming you are not doing proprietary software (gstreamer is GPL).

As you mentioned, there is at least one opencv plugin in the gstreamer code-base (which is pretty huge). It was, when last I checked, located in the gst-plugins-bad repository.

A way forward would be to pull the gstreamer source code, and build the plugins yourself. Once you can build the opencv powered plugin yourself (and test it with som appropriate gst-launch pipe) you can start to modify it to your needs. First step would be to replace the version of openCV in that plugin, to the version you have in your own project. Second step may be to get all accelerations working (as in TBB, cuda etc, depending on your platform).

After that, you can push your project into the plugin. The benefits of this is that you set your project up to work in a really efficient multimedia framework. You can also really easily get help with this on the IRC channel for gstreamer, where these developers "live" (on Freenode, in #gstreamer).

If you do not do your project as a gstreamer plugin, the only other options(last I checked) is to use [appsource](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html) and [appsink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsink.html) plugins of gstreamer. These are probably what openCV uses under the hood, if there is support these days. I would expect the version of gstreamer to be important here, so check openCV documention what version of gstreamer they built it for.

However, consider instead doing it as gstreamer plugin. It is a really cool world to enter, with many kind developers that will probably help you alot on that IRC channel.... again: that is how it was last i checked... years ago

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Finally I understood the problem. The problem was that somehow, while compiling opencv with gstreamer support on raspberry pi, opencv establish gstreamer as default backend for camera. That is why using 0 as argument didn't work, because opencv thought I was referring to a gstreamer pipeline. Documentation on opencv says the backend for camera can be specified using the index of the camera plus the backend number reference, in case of V4L it was 200. So, using 200 as argument (200 plus 0, camera 0) solved the problem and opencv was able to open the camera by V4L.